# "Failed Attempt" in MySQL Connection

Tags: mysql, persistent, connection

I am confused with MySQL connections. I have site that receives heavy requests during working hours. I use PHP to connect to MySQL database using persistant connection.
Few weeks back, I increased mysql connections to 500 that crashed my server then I put it back to 150.
Now users complaints that sometimes they cannot get on the site. I believe that this is due to limited connections.

Can you please give me some information that whether I use persistant or non-persistant? What sections of mysql do I need to tune to get optimized connection processing?
I have attached a screenshot that shows 11K Failed Attempts.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkxHP.jpg

Thank you so much...

**Update Dec 17, 2011**

When I asked this question, I changed the connection type to "non-persistant" and everything starts working fine. Today I surprised to see that the stats from phpmyadmin. Below are the values given by Phpmyadmin:

```
max. concurrent connections :: 16
Failed Attempts :: 43k
```

Please suggest some possible solutions? Which parameter should be optimized to avoid/minimize Failed attempts?

Comment: Obviously "failed attempt" comes from the fact that your site reached the max number of possible connection. Now the question is WHY did it crash when you turned it to 500 max connections ??

Comment: Thank you madkitty. It means high traffic sites should not use persistant connections since we have limited connections available in that case. Nor sure why did it crash. But that is the only change that I did before the crash.

Comment: @D3K, How did you solve this issue?

Comment: @Suriya, I set the Connection type to "non-persistent" and increased the number of connections from 150to 500. Now the failed attempts are much much lower :-)

Comment: @D3K, Thank you. By increasing the connection, did u upgrade your RAM? I am having a 8G machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

High traffic sites should not use persistent connections. I changed DB connection from persistent to non-persistent in php and problem solved!
Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:** 
 After changing connection type to non-persistent, don't forget to increase number of connections. In my case, I increased them to 500 with type set to non-persistent and that solved the issue.